# Tree, Insert Node at specific point

Tags: c++, tree

here is the think,

this is not a binary tree, 
Actually I can insert a node in left or right in the tree,
this give's this.

[image: Left - Right Nodes]

so, what i want is insert at left of the node with 5 as value:
New node below node with 5 as value , new node value 13

[image: New node below node with 5 as value , new node value 13]

The problem is when I try to insert at node with 10 as value, does not work.
Update:
Not insert node, not crash, not errors

here is the code.

```
struct bin_tree {
int data;
struct bin_tree * right;
struct bin_tree * left;
};

typedef struct bin_tree node;


enum Ruta{
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
};



void insertSide(node ** tree, int val, Ruta r)
{
    node *temp = NULL;

    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = new node();
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(r == LEFT)
    {
        if ( &(*tree)->left == NULL)
        {insert(&(*tree)->left, val);}
        else{insertSide(&((*tree)->left),val,r);}
    }
    else
    {
        if ( &(*tree)->right == NULL)
        {insert(&(*tree)->right, val);}
        else{insertSide(&((*tree)->right),val,r);}
    }
}


node * searchDeep(node ** tree,int valSearch,bool & f)
{
    node * temp;

    if((*tree))
    {
    if(valSearch == (*tree)->data)
    {
        f = true;
        temp = new node();
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->left = (*tree)->left;
        temp->right = (*tree)->right;
        temp->data = (*tree)->data;
        *tree = temp;
        return *tree;
    }
    if (f == false){
        searchDeep(&((*tree)->left), valSearch,f);
        searchDeep(&((*tree)->right), valSearch,f);
    }

    }

}

void insertAt(node ** tree, int valSearch,int valNew,Ruta r)
{
    node * temp;
    bool f;
    f =false;
    temp = searchDeep(tree,valSearch,f);
    insertSide(&temp,valNew,r);
}

int main()
{
    node *root;
    node *tmp;

    insertSide(&root,9,LEFT);
    insertSide(&root,5,RIGHT);
    insertSide(&root,10,LEFT);
    insertSide(&root,25,LEFT);
    insertSide(&root,45,LEFT);
    insertSide(&root,3,RIGHT);

    insertAt(&root,5,13,LEFT);
    //this does not work
    //insertAt(&root,10,9,RIGHT);

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

Sorry here's insert code

```
void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = new node();
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "does not work". Does it not insert it correctly? Does it crash? Is there a compiler error?

Comment: not errors, not crash, not insert the node,

Comment: Where is `insert` defined?

Comment: I see `{insert(&(*tree)->left, val);}`.

Comment: yes is true, you insert in right or left on parent node, for that i need to search the specific node and send the insert in this node, for that i pass the left or the right of specific node, for that alwas pass a empty (null) node, so, this code works for binary tree too, for that I use this.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is this test:

```
if ( &(*tree)->left == NULL)
```

Which is the same as:

```
if ( &((**tree).left) == NULL)
```

It always evaluates true because the address of left can never be null. I suggest changing the code to pass by C++ style reference instead of pointer. That would make it less confusing.

Here's some info about references:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

Comment: I think you need to step through your code with a debugger so you can see what's happening. Just because the code works sometimes doesn't mean it will always work. For example, searchDeep doesn't return anything in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `searchDeep`. If it is called with `f == false` (which it *always* is), there is no return statement. So the return value in that case is not liable to be a valid `node*`. The call in `insertAt` retains this value and then dereferences it, which will (often) be undefined behavior.

A good compiler will warn you when a non-void function can end without a `return` statement.